# Is possible restrict one profile to one device using openvpn?

Tags: openvpn

I'm using openvpn (open source version). Each user authenticates using ssl certificates. The problem is that such  a certificate can be used on any device. I'd want to restrict the usage of each certificate to only one device.

Is that feasible?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent users from logging in more than once at a given time (e.g: user has phone and laptop)? Or are you trying to "be secure" and ensure that a given key is used only by the authorized device? IMO, the former is a broken model (each device should have a separate and secret key), and there is no way to ensure the latter.

Comment: I'm trying the second one you mentioned

Comment: I don't believe that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide first how to uniquely identify a device in a satisfactory manner (for you, no silver bullet here).

That's the real question. Once you have that, then you can use a post-auth script in `openvpn` to make use of that information.

[Here](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/access-server-post-auth-script-host-checking/) is the information on post_auth scripts and this is an [example of MAC address checking](https://gist.github.com/justmiles/deba3fc680e35719cf98c7533591853e).

Comment: Does it work on open source edition?

Comment: It does, [according to their own comparison](https://openvpn.net/open-source-vs-openvpn-access-server/).

Answer (score 0):

It's hardly foolproof, but if you are using TAP you can specify the MAC address in your configuration with:

`lladdr=<MAC ADDRESS>`

The [reference manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-1/) has this to say about the option:

> **–lladdr address**
>
> Specify the link layer address, more commonly known as
> the MAC address. Only applied to TAP devices.